# Nginx ignoring some config part

Tags: nginx

I have ubuntu 14.04 server, nginx 1.10.1 and couple sites with proxy_pass on it. All works fine until i want add one more site for static content. When i try connect to my new site i suddenly get redirect to one of my old sites, like if server config for new site is empty. Further more: i decide to make new default config and it doesn't work! This my configs:

```
#new site for static content
server {
    listen          mypublicIP:80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev_proxy_access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev_proxy_error.log;
    server_name repdev.mydomain.com;

    index test.txt;
    root /data/replay;
}

#default config
server {
listen       80  default_server;
server_name  _;
error_log /var/log/nginx/default_server_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/default_server_access.log;
return       503 'Missed!';
}
```

and to this site i get redirect:

```
#force redirect to https
server {
    listen          mypublicIP:80;
    server_name crowd.mydomain.com;
    return 302 https://crowd.mydomain.com$request_uri;
 }
#proxy to localbackend
server {
    listen mypublicIP:443 ssl;
    server_name crowd.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/crowd.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/crowd.key;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/crowd_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/crowd_error.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://mylocalbackend;
        }
}
```

and this is result of curl to my new site:

```
MyaPC:~ Myafk$ curl -v repdev.mydomain.com
* Rebuilt URL to: repdev.mydomain.com/
*   Trying mypublicIP...
* Connected to repdev.mydomain.com (mypublicIP) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: repdev.mydomain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.10.1
< Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 12:46:53 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://crowd.mydomain.com/
<
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found solution. some of my sites config has 
    listen 80;
I added my public address to them and now all works properly. I think it could be sort of conflict multiple-binding to all interfaces.
Thank you, serverfault ^_^